# User re verification page .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

A page that asks the already signed in user to confirm their password one more time for security purposes on certain actions. Once confirmed it will go back to whatever request(action)they made in the first place. Should I use an user API for this? How can I achieve something like this?

```
 Public IActionResult IndexMethod()
{
//process request only if user was verified using that verification page. 
//It can take in parameters such as tokens if needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you want to confirm their password one more time for security purposes on certain actions. I suggest you could try to use action filter instead of directly going to the action and you could store the previous url into session.

More details, you could refer to below test demo:

1.Enable session:

Add below codes into Startup.cs's ConfigureServices method:

```
        services.AddSession();
```

Add below codes into Configure method:

```
        app.UseSession();
```

2.Create a filter:

```
public class ConfirmActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);


    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

        //We will store the user is comfirmed into session and check it at the filter 
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("checked")))
        {
            //store the path into session route .
            context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("route", context.HttpContext.Request.Path);
            //redirect to the confrim controller action
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Index", "Confirm", context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues);

        }



    }
}
```

3.Add confirm controller:

```
public class ConfirmController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //You could get the path 
 
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("checked","true");
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Checked() {

        // redirect to the path  user has  accessed.

        var re = HttpContext.Session.GetString("route");

        return  new RedirectResult(re);
    }

}
```

filter usage:

```
[ConfirmActionFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Result:

If the user access firstly, you will find it will go to the confirm method.

[image]